# Pro tools HD gear question

Tags: pt

So I am a little confused on what kinds of things are required for Pro Tools HD.  Basically I am running pro tools 9.  I want to do surround mixing and that would require CPTK which is 2000.00 upgrade.

In browsing used items, it seems I may be able to get an older HD system for around the same prices.  This would upgrade my IO which is a profire 2626 and provide surround capabilities.  When looking at what I need, I would need PCI card in my computer, then the IO box which would be linked to the card.

What is the difference between core cards, accell cards, and process cards.  and what am I missing from this equation.

Could someone clear up the confusion with HD systems and required hardware.

Comment: You can actually find PT10 HD licenses on eBay now for about $750. No need to be buying the CPTK.  You would need an audio interface with 6 outputs though.

Comment: Are you serious? Wouldn't one need an Avid interface? Because, that would mean Avid left a big hole in their accounting department :)
Can you explain this, I'm very interested now...

Comment: Not just an audio interface, but also at minimum the HD Native card (5k-something$). Or a legacy HD system or a new HDX system. Nothing has really changed with Avid's pricing policy..

Comment: You don't need any Avid hardware (cards, interfaces, etc) to run Pro Tools 10 HD.  I run it everyday.  You can use any audio interface.  If you do have Avid hardware, then you can run DSP based plugins, but the software will work just fine native.  Pro Tools HD software gives you the same features as Pro Tools + CPTK.

Comment: @Chuck Russom PT10HD only comes bundles with PT10HD Systems.  I cant just purchase the software :(


Answer (score 4):

Yes...if you were to stick with the native route, you would need the CPTK upgrade plus an interface that can handle a minimum of six channels of output (though it does not need to be an AVID interface with 9 and up). Looking up the Profire, it looks like it provides 8 channels of I/O. That means you would NOT need to buy a new interface.

As far as HD systems, these require a CORE card to be a basic HD1 (TDM) system. Process cards and Accel cards are the additional cards that can be added to the system to create HD2 and HD3 systems. The Accel cards are newer, and would be the better option...as I believe versions 9 and 10 require Accel cards. There are a few cavéats that go along with the idea of purchasing a used HD system:

1. The TDM systems will not support anything higher than Pro Tools 10. A hardware upgrade (PCI cards that is) would be required. Which means the upgrade will cost you another expensive outlay of cash in the future.
2. Pro Tools HD licenses are tied directly to the CORE card they are sold with. Many people who are selling their used HD systems are not including the software licenses with the hardware, which is not how the hardware is supposed to be sold. In order to upgrade from one version of Pro Tools HD to the next, you need access to the Avid account that owns the software/hardware combination. Without that you can't upgrade the software. Make sure the person selling is providing EVERYTHING the HD system originally came with, and is ready to complete a "transfer of ownership" through Avid. This gets even more complicated if you don't upgrade to 10 (another $1k minimum added to your cost...depends on the version you own) before 11 comes out. [My guess on that, probably by NAB in April...but AES 2013 at the latest).

Right now, I would argue that the CPTK is your better option. It will provide you a far easier...and cheaper...upgrade path in the future. If you ever want to go up to PT11 (whenever it comes out), an older HD system would need to be replaced entirely. There are trade-in options, but they aren't cheap...and you could be trapped if you purchase a system from the wrong person (see item 2 above). The native systems are extremely powerful, especially with recent increases to Delay Compensation in Pro Tools 10. Unless you anticipate having to complete extremely large mixes, the HD system might be overkill for you at this moment.

Comment: @Shaun Yeah I am thinking CPTK is the immediate route and then see what PT 11 has in store.  I have been told it is a complete hardware revamp and to hold off on new purchases until then.

Answer (score 0):

HD Core cards are for I/O connections and bandwidth. HD Accel cards (previously called HD Process cards) are for plug-in processing (TDM format).

At minimum you need one HD Core card to run an older version of PT HD. Obviously an I/O box of some kind (96 IO/192 IO) as well.

(Useless rant: I guess you've made a decision or have a reason to purchase PT HD, however, I would never personally pay for PT HD, given that there are so many cheaper and better options in DAWs and audio interfaces. And one can even mix surround in PT LE / the newest "normal versions", it's not ideal though.)

Comment: Cheaper and better Daws don't mean a thing when the people want me to transfer PT session files.  I also own Nuendo 5.  Dubstages here do not.  Post Prod Supers want PT workflows when I am only doing one part of the project.